# In a div how to append items from right to left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is when I am appending some icons to a div it appends from left to right but how can I append these icons from right to left.

[image][image][image]

Code:

```
$('.icons').empty();
if (data_arr[0] != ""){
            $('.icons').append('<i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        }
if (data_arr[1] != ""){
            $('.icons').append('<i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-up icon"></i></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        }
if (data_arr[2] != ""){
            $('.icons').append('<i class="fas fa-truck icon"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        }
if (data_arr[3] != ""){
            $('.icons').append('<i class="fas fa-dharmachakra"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        }
```

As you see in the pictures above.
After selecting the item from dropdown it appends an icon to above div.
I want these icons to append in div from right to left.

**Edit 1:**  Someting Like This.

[image]

Comment: Generally it's not user's comfortable solution - to show icons of selected filters only. If you concerned about user interface, it could be better solution to show all icons, but color them with light-grey color (like they not set). And after user set particular filter, make corresponding icon colored with black. This trick allows you to not bother with icons placement and rendering (your code becomes simpler and shorten) and allow users to get know by icons which filters are possible.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `.prepend()` instead of `.append()`.

```
$('.icons').prepend('<i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
```

There is also `.after()` and `.before()` jQuery functions.

Fuller example based on your code (without using font-awesome):

```
<div class="icons"></div>
```

```
$(".icons").empty();

var data_arr = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];

if (data_arr[0]) {
  $(".icons").prepend('<i class="icon">first</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}
if (data_arr[1]) {
  $(".icons").prepend('<i class="icon">second</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}
if (data_arr[2]) {
  $(".icons").prepend('<i class="icon">third</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}
if (data_arr[3]) {
  $(".icons").prepend('<i class="icon">fourth</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, @BenHerbert It appends it left. but what I want is that first icon in right most place of div and then prepend other elements to it.

Comment: @RohitPandey, you could just define `.icons {float: right;}`

Comment: Good point @Banzay! :-D plus a little padding here and there, you got it.

Comment: Sorry @RohitPandey - I think I don't understand then. You want the truck to be the last icon, not the first right? I think my solution should work for you no?

Answer (score 0):

You could either re-arrange it so that it end ups looking how you want it or you could as well use jQuery `insertBefore()` method. I made the following examples to see which one would be better for you.

```js
$('.icons').empty();

var data_arr = ['1','2','3','4']

$('.icons').append('<i class="first-icon far fa-calendar icon"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');

$('<i class="fas fa-dharmachakra"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;').insertBefore(".first-icon");

$('<i class="fas fa-truck icon"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;').insertBefore(".first-icon");

$('<i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-up icon"></i></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;').insertBefore(".first-icon");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<div class='icons'>
</div>
```

```js
$('.icons').empty();

var data_arr = ['1','2','3','4']


if (data_arr[0] != ""){
            $('.icons').append('<i class="fas fa-dharmachakra"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}
if (data_arr[1] != ""){
            $('.icons').append('<i class="fas fa-truck icon"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}    
if (data_arr[2] != ""){
            $('.icons').append('<i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-up icon"></i></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}
if (data_arr[3] != ""){
            $('.icons').append('<i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<div class='icons'>
</div>
```

Comment: Smart to link to font-awesome CSS yourself.

Comment: Just an added detail to the answer :)